# How can I remove all the elements in python html text where tag exists as a sibling element

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I need to parse the dirty html string in python where I need to eliminate all the texts which have sibling tag next to it .

For example, I need to convert this html.

```
    <p class="se_textarea">
        x3C!-- SE3-TEXT { --&gt;
    <span>
        <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
        nnnnnnn
        <br>
    </span>
    <span>
        <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    </p>
```

to this html.

```
    <p class="se_textarea">
    <span>
        <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    <span>
        <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
       <br>
    </span>
    </p>
```

Since `x3C!-- SE3-TEXT { --&gt;` is a sibling of `<span>` and  nnnnn is a sibling of `<b>`tag I need to remove this texsts while `식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등` is the only text in the `<b>` tag I don't need to remove it.

Comment: what is the sibling tag next to the text you want to remove?

Comment: @Maaz it depends it could be div span or p

Comment: It's not so easy to understand. In your exemple, why did you remove `nnnnnnn` ? Because the next tag is a `<br>`?

Comment: @Maaz because I need to display those html and nnnnn is dirty data that I don't need

Comment: Yes but with the llogical way, how did you find it? I mean, why `nnnnnnn` and not `식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등`

Comment: I get data from my client's page. I want delete nnnnnn because it have same level sibling '<b>' tag while 식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등 does not have sibling it is only child of <b> tag.

Comment: @Maaz Thanks to your question I edit the question to make it more easy to understands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, this is ultra specific partially because you really only provided one example so I'm not sure what kind of tags will come so you have 2 options.

**Indeed regex isn't usually the best for html, but I do hope this helps. BeautifulSoup or lxml may ultimately be better.**

**Using re.sub (for Python3) you can use distance if the formatting is relatively consistent so here I'm saying replace any text that doesn't begin with `<` if it is preceded by 7 or more spaces**

```
>>> import re



>>> string = '''<p class="se_textarea">
        <span>
            <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
            nnnnnnn
            <br>
        </span>
        <span>
            <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
           <br>
        </span>
        </p>'''



>>> print(re.sub('(?m)\n[\ ]{7,}(?!<)[\S]+(?=\n|$)', '', string))


    #OUTPUT
    <p class="se_textarea">
    <span>
        <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    <span>
        <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    </p>
```

.

**OR you can use a specific regex and substitute the tag names where necessary**

```
>>> import re



>>> string = '''<p class="se_textarea">
        <span>
            <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
            nnnnnnn
            <br>
        </span>
        <span>
            <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
           <br>
        </span>
        </p>'''



>>> print(re.sub(r'(<span>[\S\s]*?<[\S\s]*?>[\S\ ]*?</[\S\s]*?>[\s]*?)([\S\s]*?)(\n[\ ]+<)', r'\1\3', string))


    #OUTPUT
    <p class="se_textarea">
    <span>
        <b>식탁등/카페조명/매장/포인트조명/pc방/티 테이블 등등</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    <span>
        <b>어느곳에 설치 하셔도 예쁜..&nbsp;</b>
        <br>
    </span>
    </p>
```